# Оптимизация изображений в галерее

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток :)

Когда-то давно сделал простенькую галерею, используя пару плагинов от Desandro - Masonry и ImagesLoaded. Ввиду того, что картинок было мало(15-40 шт), об оптимизации как-то не задумывался(full hd картинки были в контейнере шириной 300-400px), тем более использовалось всё это дело исключительно для себя. Но теперь мне нужно организовать вывод нескольких сотен различных картинок и просто "забить" я не хочу, хотелось бы, чтобы всё нормально и быстро прогружалось, ну и, конечно же, не совать большие картинки в маленький контейнер.

В этом и суть моего вопроса. Помогите, пожалуйста, как правильно подогнать разрешение изображения под ширину контейнера(соблюдая пропорции, конечно же)? Если что, все картинки выгружаются на стороне сервера из БД.

На готовый пример не претендую, но хотелось бы узнать подробнее об этой технологии :)
Буду рад любой помощи.

P.S. Приблизительный пример того, о чём я говорю, можно увидеть на [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/). У них в сетке картинки чуть больше контейнера, в котором они лежат.

Answer (score 0):

В запросах прямо указаны необходимые размеры. Как все это обрезается на сервере - другой вопрос

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507915600431-5292809c5ab7?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=376&h=251&q=60&cs=tinysrgb&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D

Меняем w=376 и h=251 на что угодно, получаем новое изображение